# Unix- How to return +,-,0 depending on integer inputted?

Tags: unix

I would like to create shell script that echos a + if the inputted integer is a positive, echos a "-" if the inputted integer is a negative, and echos a "0" if its not any of those.

So my script is like this:

```
echo "Enter an Integer"
read declare -i var1
if((var1>0))
then  
    echo +
elif (( var1<0))
    then echo -
else echo 0
fi
```

I keep getting a bad variable name error and var1 not found.

Answer (score 2):

I got the script to work by separating the `read` and `declare` lines.

```
echo "Enter an Integer"
declare -i var1
read var1
if((var1>0))
then
    echo +
elif (( var1<0))
    then echo -
else echo 0
fi
```

Console log (running on OS X):

```
$ bash e.sh
Enter an Integer
972
+
$ bash e.sh
Enter an Integer
-32
-
$ bash e.sh
Enter an Integer
0
0
```

Comment: Oh ok , thanks! So I cannot simply just " read the declaration" . Probably the same for other variables also. I should read it as " declare variable first THEN read it"?

Comment: That's correct. The [built-in `read` function](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_08_02.html) requires names as arguments, not a series of tokens beginning with `declare`. :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to `read` and then test your values. Something like

```
echo "Enter an Integer"
read var1
if [[ "$var1" -gt 0 ]]
then
    echo +
elif [[ "$var1" -lt 0 ]]
then
    echo -
else
    echo 0
fi
```

works here.